# error de sintaxys lambda

Tags: python

```
def menorValorNoProcesado(etiquetas, procesados):
    etiquetadosSinProcesar = filter(lambda (nodo,_):not nodo in procesados, etiquetas.iteritems())
    return min(etiquetadosSinProcesar, key=lambda (_, (acum, __)): acum)[0]
```

Comment: hola, pudieras poner el error que te aparece, o al menos una explicacion, gracias

Comment: En la línea del return te falta un paréntesis de cierre final, por otro lado, deberías mostrar el error y qué intentas hacer como comenta muy correctamente sgClaudia, considera agregar también  un [mcve]. Saludos.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yruEjgVabuHdgxueZiYECx1Va3C_6vEm/view?usp=sharing ese es el codigo

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

La función `lambda` se caracteriza por el hecho de que puede recibir cualquier cantidad de argumentos, pero solo puedes retornar un valor.

Teniendo esto claro, los errores de sintaxis en la función `lambda` son varios:

1. No requiere de un paréntesis para encerrar los argumentos, su correctas sintaxis es la siguiente: `lambda x,y: x + y`.
2. No puede retornar mas de un valor, le pides que retorne la cantidad de dos valores.
3. `lambda` es una función anónima, no puedes invocarla.

En solución, te recomiendo que definas esa `lambda` como otra función en tu código:

```
def funcion(a,b):
    return not nodo in procesados,etiquetas.iteritems()

def menorValorNoProcesado(etiquetas, procesados):
    etiquetadosSinProcesar = filter(funcion(nodo,_))

    return min(etiquetadosSinProcesar,key = funcion(_,(acum,__)):acum)[0]
```

No sé el contexto de tu código así que no sé lo que estás haciendo, además encuentro otro errores de sintaxis en tu código.

Espero que te yude xD

Comment: Observa que `etiquetas.iteritems()` no es parte de la expresión lambda, es el segundo argumento de `filter`. Además, es cierto una expresión lambda no puede retornar dos valores, pero igual que que una función normal, lo que si puede igual que ésta, es retornar una tupla: `list(map(lambda n: (n**2, n**3), (3, 4, 5))`. Hacer `return n**2, n**3` es solo azúcar sintáctica para `return (n**2, n**3)`. Por último, una función lambda por supuesto que es invocable, si no no sería una función: `(lambda n: (n**2, n**3))(3)`. Incluso puedes asignarla a una variable `fun = lambda: print("hola")` ; `fun()`

Comment: El punto uno si es totalmente cierto, posiblemente sea la causa de su error y de su pregunta, dado el poco contexto que el OP da tenemos que adivinar muchas cosas desgraciadamente...